# How to use a RubyGems class in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need to stream a TAR file using data from the database in a Rails app. 
I know that RubyGems has the `TarWriter` module that suits my use case perfectly.

The question is, how can I include the module in my Rails app?
I tried to require rubygems/package as follows:

```
require 'zlib'
require 'rubygems/package'

tar = StringIO.new

Gem::Package::TarWriter.new(tar) do |writer|
    writer.add_file("a_file.txt", 0644) do |f| 
        (1..1000).each do |i| 
            f.write("some text\n")
        end
    end
    writer.add_file("another_file.txt", 0644) do |f| 
        f.write("some more text\n")
    end
end
tar.seek(0)

gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(File.new('this_is_a_tar_gz.tar.gz', 'wb'))
gz.write(tar.read)
tar.close
gz.close
```

The `require` failed on the controller. I tried to adding `gem 'rubygems/package'` on my `Gemfile` but it didn't work.

It's a noob question, how can I use RubyGems modules from a Rails app?

Comment: What kind of error are you receiving?

Comment: NameError - uninitialized constant Hostmanager::HostsController::TarWriter:

Answer (score 0):

You should specify full path to module: `Gem::Package::TarWriter` and add `require 'rubygems/package'` to your controller.